# User ID returned as 0 for non-admin users when logged in to the site- Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, controller, drupal-8

I have a dashboard controller where I show the dashboard to users who are not anonymous. My controller code is as below:

```
class DashboardController extends ControllerBase {  
    protected $currentUser;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(AccountProxy $current_user) {
        $this->currentUser = $current_user;
    }

    //HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS. FOR NON-ADMIN USERS, THE USERID IS RETURNED AS 0
    public function access(AccountInterface $account) {
      dd($this->currentUser);
      if (!$this->currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
            return AccessResult::forbidden();
        } else {
            return AccessResult::allowed();
        }

    //FUNCTION TO DISPLAY DASHBOARD
    public function accessDashboard(AccountInterface $account) {
    $current_user = $this->currentUser;
      $roles = $current_user->getRoles();
      $current_user_record = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($current_user->id());
      if (!$current_user->isAuthenticated()) {
        return AccessResult::forbidden();
      }
      if ($current_user->hasPermission('view school dashboard')) {
        //SHOW THE ASSOCIATED SCHOOL NAMES DASHBOARD
      } 
      return AccessResult::forbidden();
    }
}
```

Screenshot of what I see when logged in as a non-admin user:

[image]

When logging in as an Administrator, I can clearly see the user ID and details as below:

[image]

any help on how to handle this problem?

Comment: The `$this->current_user`  was assigned by `__construction()`, which inherit its parent. Could you show where the initial of the `$current_user` is?

Comment: current_user is coming from module.service:

Comment: my_module.redirect_subscriber:
    class: \Drupal\my_module\EventSubscriber\mymodRedirectSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_user', '@current_route_match']
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, if a visitor/user not logged in (Anonymous User) then they will share the UID of 0.

You can find this from the below doc:
[Drupal - User Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/understanding-drupal/users-permissions-and-roles)

Also, in your first screenshot the object you dump is of **AnonymousUserSession** which is the implementation representing anonymous users. So I think there are no authenticated users yet.

[Drupal - Class AnonymousUserSession](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AnonymousUserSession.php/class/AnonymousUserSession/9.3.x)

Comment: That screenshot is after I logged in as a user. Not anonymous

Comment: You don't need to Inject CurrentUser since you're extending `ControllerBase`. What is the output for `$this->currentUser->isAnonymous()` ? 

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/property/ControllerBase%3A%3AcurrentUser/9.3.x